# Are questions that may come up on the oral portion of the practical test on topic?

Tags: discussion

It would be great for Aviation.SE to develop comprehensive study guides for the oral portions of the practical tests for PPL, CPL, IR, and so on — particularly for some of the tricky or at least less obvious questions that may come up. I’m thinking of a new tag, say `[oral-exam-questions]`, to be paired with `[ppl]`, `[cpl]`, or other appropriate certificate levels.

Would such a series of questions be on topic?

Comment: I think some comments in [my answer](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1513/62) to another question might apply here too: SE isn't about pre-selected and curated information. Your proposal also sounds very US-centric to me.

Comment: So make it three tags: `[oral-exam-questions]`, `[ppl]`, and `[faa]`.

Answer (score 5):

A study guide in the form of lists of questions that may appear is bad form for SE, but asking individual questions should be fine.  I wouldn't spam the whole ASA study guide, but rather stick to difficult to understand questions.  One example of such a question already on the site is [What do the terms 'holding out' and 'common carriage' mean?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/what-do-the-terms-holding-out-and-common-carriage-mean) This has implications well beyond the practical test, but is certainly something you'd expect to talk about in a commercial oral.

I would argue against a tag like "oral-exam-questions" as that would be considered a meta-tag that doesn't really stand on its own.

Comment: That's the idea: a series of questions in that tag where each question is one that an applicant might expect, and all together the questions across that tag comprise a study guide.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that a comprehensive study guide is really a good fit for any SE site. It certainly wouldn't fit in a question, and the [blog](http://aviation.blogoverflow.com/) doesn't really fit either.

Alternatively, a group of questions tagged with [oral-exam-questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-exam-questions) might work better for collecting info - but, again, I don't think that's a great fit here. For example, just about any FAR questions are fair game during an oral exam - and we've got an [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations) tag already. [Some questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/what-do-the-terms-holding-out-and-common-carriage-mean?s=1%7C1.7665) are almost guaranteed to be discussed in the oral, but (particularly for the oral) it would be difficult to draw a line of what does or doesn't belong there.